# Not working "onclick()" with a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have an application which uses some Tabs. The functionality of these tabs is programmed with jquery (I dont know how to program jquery). So if I want to add a Tab I use this line:

```
<div class="tab">1</div>
```

I didnt program the function of that tab, but I need to add some other functions, so I am trying to use  `onclick()` on the DIV (as next) but does not work.

```
<div class="tab" onclick="prueba()">1</div>
```

In order to make it work, I need to use something like this:

```
<div class="tab"><span onclick="prueba()">1</span></div>
```

My problem is that the size of the DIV is bigger, so the `onclick()` would only work by clicking exactly on the number, rather tahn any part of the div.

I already tryied to insert the DIV inside the Span (as next) but does not work.

```
<span onclick="prueba()"><div class="tab">1</div></span>
```

Does anyone know if this is happening because of jquery which is controling the functions on the tab??

Is there any way to use any element with `onclick()` outside the DIV with the "tab" class??

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my english

```
function prueba() {
   alert("HELLO");
}
```

Sorry not to put the jquery code, it is too long and I dont know exactly which part to show.

Comment: Knowing what the `prueba` function does would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from this "*I have an application which uses some Tabs. The functionality of these tabs is programmed with jquery (I dont know how to program jquery). So if I want to add a Tab I use this line:*"

it would sound as tho the jquery is looking for the "tab" class. I would suggest posting the jquery OR assigning the tab class to whatever element you wish to have trigger the action

ie:

`<span class="tab" onclick="prueba()"><div >1</div></span>`

would probably fire ( unless it wants a div.tab ) ? Lets guess!

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered just using `$('.tab').click(prueba)` or something along those lines? That's how you're generally meant to do this sort of thing with jQuery.